# javascript code for html frame is not woking

Tags: javascript

I have frameset with 3 frames, javascript code is not working unable to understand why?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML Frames</title>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="10%,80%,10%">
    <frame name="top" src="frame/frame1.html" />
    <frame name="main" src="frame/frame2.html" />
    <frame name="bottom" src="frame/frame3.html" />
  </frameset>

  <body>
    <script>
      alert('hi');
      var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('frameset')[0];
      iframe.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned what exactly is not working, I am going to assume here.

You are calling the wrong HTML tag. You need to get the 'frame' tag and not the 'frameset' tag for retrieving the first iframe.

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[0];
```

Hope this helps.